# Can I find the asymptotes of a function knowing the derivative?

Tags: integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Given for example
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^3+2t+e^t}{2t^2+2e^t}e^{-t^2}dt$$ for $x \to +\infty$ can I say if it has asymptotes and if so, which ones, without integrating?

Comment: If you just need to show that there exists an asymptote, without actually identifying it, you don't need to integrate, you just need to show that the improper integral is convergent.

Comment: @PierreCarre yes, I only need to show that there exists

Comment: @PierreCarre: mh, an oblique asymptote corresponds to a diverging integral.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are correct, for some reason I assumed horizontal asymptotes. But if the integral is convergente there is no oblique asymptote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question of the title : the answer is no. For example, $f(x)=0$ (and thus $f'(x)\to 0$ whenever $x\to \infty $) has an asymptote at $+\infty $ which is given by the line $y=0$, whereas, $g(x)=\ln(x)$ is s.t. $g'(x)\to 0$ whenever $x\to \infty $, but $g$ has no asymptote at $+\infty $.

Answer (score 0):

If the improper integral is convergent there is an horizontal asymptote. If it isn't, the slope of oblique asymptotes $y=mx$, can be compute $m$ using L'Hopital's rule:
$$
m = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{I(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{\frac{x^3+2x+e^x}{2x^2+2 e^x}\cdot e^{-x^2}}{1}=0
$$

So, either there is an horizontal asymptote or no asymptote at all.

Bottom line: Check if the integral is convergent. If it is, there is a horizontal asymptote; If it isn't, there is no asymptote.